# Typo3 is really driving me crazy

Tags: typo3, extbase

my findbypay ( pay beeing here as a parameter) returns the exact number of entries in the database but the objects are null ...

here is how I use it in an action :

```
public function getMyCompanysAction()
{
      $argument = $this->request->getArguments('id');
      $companies = $this->entrepriseRepository->findBypay(2)->toArray(); // just to test with the id 2
      return json_encode($companies);
}
```

the outputed json contains 3 arrays but are all empty .. [{},{},{}].

how could this really happen ? knowing that when I use the same method and assign it to the view , the objects are complete and 
I mean this way :

```
public function listAction()
 {
   $this->view->assign('lists', $this->entrepriseRepository->findBypays(2));
 }
```

Comment: How is `findByPay()` implemented? The title of your question is not summarizing your question. Please adjust.

Comment: Or use getArguments()  (multiple) or use getArgument('value') (single)   also use the correct naming conventions : findByPropertyname